# Zend Framework 2 Union Select with order

Tags: php, sql, database, zend-framework2

I have this Sql code:

```
( SELECT `column1` FROM `table_1` WHERE `column2` > 2 )
UNION
( SELECT `column1` FROM `table_2` WHERE `column2` < 10 )
ORDER BY `column1` ASC;
```

How to do that with Zend Framework 2?

Answer (score 0):

Zend Framework 2 Zend\Db\Sql does not provide a Union method yet you'll have to either write it yourself or use a JOIN.

```
$sql = new Sql($this->adapter);
$select = $sql->select();
$select->from($this->table)
       ->join('table_1', 'table_2.column1 = table_1.column1');

$where = new  Where();
$where->greaterThan('column2', 2) ; //youll have to add a and here with a lessThan
$select->where($where);

$statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
$result = $statement->execute();
```

Honestly speaking I did not try this example, but it should atleast give you a Idea.